# Tcl version not recognized in Anaconda/Spyder/Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda, tcl

I installed in Anaconda the tk package which is 8.6.10. I run Python 3.8.5
When I run within Spyder IDE the simple script

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
```

I got the classic message "TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:"
In the list of directories reported I do have tcl.
I tried in the cmd from anaconda to run tclsh and wish and they are both working. By running wish and looking for the version it reports correctly Tcl and Tk 8.6.10

So I took the C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\lib\tcl8.6\init.tcl and moved it in C:/ProgramData/library  as this is one of the directories I get in the error report.
When I do this I got another error "C:/ProgramData/library/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6.10"

So it is clear that the tclsh in bin and the init.tcl are not from the same version (why?) but how can now enforce a correct behavior of my python script looking for the right Tcl/Tk?
I was expecting this to work out of the box

p.s. THe directory "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\lib\tcl8.6" is also in the list of directories that is returned by the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the version of the DLLs that are being used (which might be `TCL86.DLL` and `TK86.DLL` on Windows, but the exact names can vary) must match exactly the version of their support files (the primary one is `init.tcl`, but there's a lot more besides). That's a hard requirement; the software checks it (rightly!) and definitely won't work without them. As the binary code is looking for the files from 8.6.9 and yet has the files from 8.6.10 (a version mismatch) it's not going to work. (I don't know exactly how Tkinter was built.)

But at least we know what files it is looking for, and exactly where to get them. The official release of Tcl and Tk 8.6.9 is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.6.9/ so get `tcl869-src.zip` *and* `tk869-src.zip` from there, and copy the contents of the `library` directory in each ZIP to where you want them to be (presumably one of the directories that are searched for). You don't need to do anything fancier than that, except perhaps to delete the old mismatched files if they're earlier on the path.

Comment: If someone needs a different exact version, the URLs are deliberately ultra-predictable.